# How do I enter "ř" (small R with caron) and other unusual special characters on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, keyboard, contacts, internationalization

I have a Czech friend whose name is Jiří, and I want to add his name to my Contacts.  Pressing and holding R on the iPhone keyboard does not show any special character versions (and similarly on OSX, holding R doesn't show anything.  I found the character in Special Characters on OSX.)

How can I add his name to my iPhone contacts?  More generally, how do you get access to general special characters on the iPhone?  I don't know of any Special Characters equivalent app or functionality accessible through the keyboard, but I would guess there must be a way somehow.

Answer (score 4):

That character is not accessible from the English iPhone keyboard. You can, however, enable other keyboards on your iPhone.

Under the **Settings** app, go to **General** then **Keyboards** and select the **Keyboards** control. You can then touch **Add New Keyboard…** and add the Czech keyboard as an option.

When typing, if you want to access the<kbd>ř</kbd> key, hold down the globe key on the bottom row of the keyboard, select the Czech layout, and then when you press and hold <kbd>r</kbd>, you get the menu wherein you can select the ř.

If you frequently need Czech accents, keep the Czech keyboard installed. If this is a rare occurrence, you can then uninstall the Czech keyboard from **Settings** » **General** » **Keyboards** » **Keyboards**.

---

The easier way to access the ř character on a one-time basis would be to visit *this page* with your iPhone, copy the ř character, and then paste it into your friend's Contact information.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I never thought of adding another keyboard. Re the one-time basis - yes, I thought of that, or sending myself an email with the character, etc... but I was sure there had to be a better way! Especially if I'm not at home and don't have my Mac handy.

Comment: The fact that you typed the character in the question means you had *some* way of producing it :-)

Comment: Yes - but it took until I got home and was at my computer to do so! Once I'm there I might as well add the contact manually and sync. I figured there *had* to be a way to do it on the phone itself.

Answer (score 1):

For general access to special characters on iOS devices there are also various apps like Unicode Pad and Cymbol.  Some characters cannot be found on any keyboard.